# Weird router reset when saving settings in ispConfig

Tags: linux, router

Okay this is probably going to come across as very weird, I can't say i have ever heard of anything like it until it started happening.

At first i thought it was a coincidence but trying it several times at varying times of day the result is still the same. Whenever I update anything on my local server my broadband router cycles.

Setup: Hub One (plusnet wireless router/modem)
Server: on Lan, basic ubuntu server with ISPConfig and the usual services for running mail, dns etc etc Nothing too fancy or heavy.
Wifi: (Dual band d n ac etc with probably 8 - 10 devices connected at max)

This is strange because i first noticed it when the update of the dns was taking an unsually long time, the wifi dropped out on the laptop i was working from so it lead me to investigate.

I found the router was mid cycle and since ive been watching it every time ive made changes on the server via ISPConfig.

I've not been able to find anything in searching about it with ispconfig, just posts about various windows causing routers to reset (I use ubuntu on all of my systems).

Any help on resolving this please as it is now driving me potty and i don't know where to begin.

Comment: First, tried another router?

Comment: Not yet, il try the old one in the morning, this is a brand new one sent out during a fault tracking escapade which turned out to be at the cabinet our fibre is served. Not sure why this was migrated here, seems odd as the only time it happens is when im working on the server but maybe this is a better place.